# Changing the number of cores while parallel computing in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm executing parallelized code in R using the `parallel` package and `mclapply` which takes a predefined number of cores as a parameter.

If I have a job that is going to run for a couple days, is there a way for me to write (or wrap) my `mclapply` function to use fewer cores during peak server hours and ramp up the usage in off-peak hours?

Comment: I guess you have to add a layer to mclapply. Basically split your list of jobs in batches. Each batch will be performed by a mclapply. Before running a new batch, you can look at your server state, then decide the appropriate number of cores to run the next batch.

Comment: @KarlForner Yes, that's also how I would do it.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the easiest solution would be to split your data into smaller sized chunks and run `mclapply` separately on those chunks. Then you can set the number of cores for each run of `mclapply`. This works probably better with calculations that have little variance w.r.t. run-time.

I have created a little quick-and-dirty mock-up of how this could look like:

```
library(parallel)
library(lubridate)

#you would have to come up with your own function
#for the number of cores to be used
determine_cores=function(hh) {
  #hh will be the hour of the day
  if (hh>17|hh<9) {
    return(4)
  } else {
    return(2)
  }
}

#prepare some sample data
set.seed(1234)
myData=lapply(seq(1e-1,1,1e-1),function(x) rnorm(1e7,0,x))

#calculate SD with mclapply WITHOUT splitting of data into chunks
#we need this for comparison
compRes=mclapply(myData,function(x) sd(x),mc.cores=4)

set.seed(1234)
#this will hold the results of the separate mclapply calls
res=list()
#starting position within myData
chunk_start_pos=1
calc_flag=TRUE

while(calc_flag) {
  #use the function defined above to determine how many cores we may use
  core_num=determine_cores(lubridate::hour(Sys.time()))
  #determine end position of data chunk
  chunk_end_pos=chunk_start_pos+core_num-1
  if (chunk_end_pos>=length(myData)) {
    chunk_end_pos=length(myData)
    calc_flag=FALSE
  }
  message("Calculating elements ",chunk_start_pos," to ",chunk_end_pos)
  #mclapply call on data chunk
  #store data in res
  res[[length(res)+1]]=mclapply(myData[chunk_start_pos:(chunk_start_pos+core_num-1)],
                                function(x) sd(x),
                                mc.preschedule=FALSE,
                                mc.cores=core_num)
  #calculate new start position
  chunk_start_pos=chunk_start_pos+core_num
}

#let's compare the results
all.equal(compRes,unlist(res,recursive=FALSE))
#TRUE
```